# Probability of Two Tails Given At Least One Tail

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A coin was flipped 3 times. What is the probability that exactly 2 tails were obtained, given that at least 1 tail was obtained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a question about [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability).

Ordinarily for a coinflipping question with three fair coins, the sample space would look something like this:

$$\{TTT,TTH,THT,HTT,THH,HTH,HHT,HHH\}$$

We are told however that *at least one tail was obtained*.  As a result, our sample space can no longer contain $HHH$ as it would contradict the statement "*given that at least 1 tail was obtained*."

Our new sample space is then just $\{TTT,TTH,THT,HTT,THH,HTH,HHT\}$

More generally the statement:  "The probability of event $A$ occurring *given that event $B$ occurs*" corresponds to the expression:

$$Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{Pr(A\cap B)}{Pr(B)}$$

Comment: When all outcomes are equally likely (as they are in this case), I like the equivalent expression $$\operatorname{Pr}(A \mid B) = \frac{|A \cap B|}{|B|}.$$ Conceptually, this reinforces the idea that one is merely counting successes in the new "restricted" sample space.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $A$ be at least obtaining 1 Tail and $B$ obtaining exactly 2 Tails.

then:

$P(B \mid A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$

Also you can notice that $B \subset A$ so $A \cap B=B$, then

$P(B \mid A)=\frac{P(B)}{P(A)}$